# Responsive tabs in foundation 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

how can I make the tabs responsive by using foundation framework?

I am getting the output like this in the responsive window:

[image]

```
    <ul class="tabs" data-tab role="tablist">
  <li class="tab-title active" role="presentational" ><a href="#panel2-1" role="tab" tabindex="0"    aria-selected="true" controls="panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title" role="presentational" ><a href="#panel2-2" role="tab" tabindex="0"aria-selected="false" controls="panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title" role="presentational"><a href="#panel2-3" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" controls="panel2-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title" role="presentational" ><a href="#panel2-4" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" controls="panel2-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" class="content active" id="panel2-1">
    <h2>First panel content goes here...</h2>
  </section>
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-2">
    <h2>Second panel content goes here...</h2>
  </section>
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-3">
   <h2>Third panel content goes here...</h2>
  </section>
  <section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" class="content" id="panel2-4">
    <h2>Fourth panel content goes here...</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: tabs are responsive in foundation..

Comment: but the above code is not working

Answer (score -1):

If you may, please provide a link (or publish your work online) for a better response.

Have you read the docs yet?

- [Zurb Accordion](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html)
- [Zurb Tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html)

If you look closer, there is an example on both pages. According to your screenshot, the responsive foundation 5 tabs look exactly how they should. Also, consider doing a web search for "responsive bookmarklet tools" for results that can help a-bit more than Chrome's inspector or FF's Firebug.

Replace your code with this snippet, and along the way, replace with the content you need - one tab at-a-time:

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
    <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1">Tab 1</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel3">Tab 3</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="panel1">
        <p>This is the first panel of the basic tab example. This is the first panel of the basic tab example.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel2">
        <p>This is the second panel of the basic tab example. This is the second panel of the basic tab example.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel3">
        <p>This is the third panel of the basic tab example. This is the third panel of the basic tab example.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But when I change the tab name like 'America','Europe' and 'Africa', the alignment is the same as I posted.

Comment: Mhmm, so you don't have a link to share?